# How to login into a page using Python requests or urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

I've been trying to login into this website https://app.drillinginfo.com/gallery/ using Python and requests but I can't manage the session. I can't use Selenium, so I need a method in requests or urllib. Can anyone help me?

Here's the code I used before:

```
import requests
r = requests.Session()
payload = {'username':'password'}
r.post('https://app.drillinginfo.com/gallery/', data = payload)

data = r.get('https://app.drillinginfo.com/gallery/').text
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't log me in.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in an actual username and password.

```
payload = {'username': 'YOURUSERNAME', 'password': 'YOURPASSWORD'}
url = 'https://app.drillinginfo.com/gallery/'
requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Mitchell. I've tried your solution with the actual username and password but I can't log in yet. I need to simulate the login session but I can't. I managed to do it in Selenium but Selenium takes a very long time, so I need something in requests or urllib.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `r.auth = ('user', 'password')` or you should log in through their API if they've provided it